# Display array in multi-column table using template tookit?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have an array of phone numbers. I want to display these numbers in a table, 5 numbers per row. Can I do this in Template Toolkit without modifying my data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin [Template::Plugin::Table](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Plugin/Table.html):

```
[% USE table(phone_numbers, cols=5) %]

[% FOREACH row IN table.rows %]
   [% FOREACH item IN row %]
      [% item %]
   [% END %]
[% END %]
```

`phone_numbers` is a reference to the phone number array which should be passed to Template Toolkit. Example:

```
...
$data->{phone_numbers} = \@phone_numbers;

$template->process('example.tmpl', $data) 
   || die "Template processing failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";
```